# Empathy / Google Talk going offline

Tags: networking, empathy

I am experiencing a problem with Empathy/Google Talk disconnecting and ultimately going offline. I have two systems, one desktop and one laptop where Empathy/Google Talk seemingly conflict with each other. If I run Empathy/Google Talk on both systems at the same time I get a series of -Disconnected -Connected messages followed by Empathy on one and sometimes both systems going offline.

Both systems are running Ubuntu 14.10 (64 bit).

Other information:
  Network Proxy is set to none (applied system wide) for both systems 
  The Desktop is internet connected via wired (IP:192.168.1.72) 
  The Laptop is internet connected via wireless (IP:192.168.1.70)
Edit:
empathy version 3.8.6 Google Talk version unknown

I'll be happy to provide any additional information needed.

I don't see a way to attach files. If someone can help I will attach two files with the installed packages for each system.

Comment: Just thinking outside the box here as I don't use either ATM, but could this be related to port forwarding/triggering in your router?

Comment: Good question, didn't think of that. Just checked the router... it is not doing any port forwarding.

Comment: Additional note: Both systems are running empathy version 3.8.6.

Comment: You might find this interesting. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EmpathyVsPidginUsability#Google_Talk You may also wish to edit your question and also include your version of google talk. It might be relevant.

Comment: @ElderGeek<P>
Sorry my question isn't clear. I'll attribute that to poor understanding of the problem. Actually the symptom is confusing and as for the root of the problem I don't have a clue.<P> 

I don't know the version of Google Talk. I use Empathy to login to Google Talk. Google Talk is not an installed package.<P>

Comment: Originally I thought the problem is a conflict between my two systems (both on, problem - one off, no problem); however, yesterday I had the problem with only one system on. So I have to ask myself, is there a conflict or was yesterday an aberration. Today supports it being an aberration.<P>

Most of the time I connect with my wife at her work. When I setup the connection it was strange so perhaps its the problem. Her work account is apparently Jabber so today I'll try get a Jabber account and see if that fixes the issue.<P>

Comment: This is a tough one considering we don't know whether there is some port configuration that may or may not be blocked at your wifes work as well. Please keep us posted and share your solution! Thank you!

Comment: This is a workaround: If you have the Google Chrome installed, install the [Chrome Hangout App](http://techcrunch.com/2014/10/09/google-hangouts-is-now-a-dedicated-app-for-chrome-os-and-windows-pcs/). Once installed it will start-up when you log in and it should work even if you have not started up Chrome yet. This bypasses the whole Empathy/Google-Talk issue.

Comment: It doesn't look like I will get my hands on my wife's work computer anytime soon. What I have done is (a couple weeks ago) I installed Pidgin on all my computers and quit using Empathy. So far I have not seen the problem with Pidgin. If I get the opportunity with my wife's computer I'll see what I can find, in the meantime I'm closing this issue. If I get new information I'll update it.